# 1gravity contacts picker library for android

Tags: android

Has anyone used [1GravityContactsPicker](https://github.com/1gravity/Android-ContactPicker) Library for android.

I just found this yesterday and decided to use this in my app due to its good features. I did everything as mentioned in the steps but when i am starting the activity I am getting a Toast message saying

> Attribute undefined; "cp_textColorPrimary". Did you apply the correct
>   theme

i have checked the documentation of library and heres what i did
1) Added dependency to gradle
2) Added activity file to manifest
3) Enabled contacts permission
4) below is the code

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContactPickerActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_THEME, R.style.ContactPicker_Theme_Dark)

                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT_BADGE_TYPE,
                                ContactPictureType.ROUND.name())

                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT_DESCRIPTION,
                                ContactDescription.ADDRESS.name())
                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_CHECK_ALL, true)
                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_SELECT_CONTACTS_LIMIT, 0)
                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_ONLY_CONTACTS_WITH_PHONE, false)

                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT_DESCRIPTION_TYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK)

                        .putExtra(ContactPickerActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT_SORT_ORDER,
                                ContactSortOrder.AUTOMATIC.name());

                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONTACT);
            }
        });
```

can anyone please help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue. 
it's because in his Actvity he test the AppThem directly and if your Application themes does not implement Picker style the check is all time false.

```
// check if all custom attributes are defined
    if (! checkTheming()) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

For fix it, i've juste add new themes in styles.xml

```
    <!-- LIGHT Theme -->
<style name="Theme_Light_Base" parent="@style/ContactPicker_Theme_Light">
    <!-- ActionBarCompat -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary_light</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark_light</item>

    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/background_light</item>
    <!--<item name="icTheme">@drawable/ic_palette_black_36dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="icPickContact">@drawable/ic_person_add_black_36dp</item>-->
</style>

<style name="Theme_Light_picker" parent="@style/Theme_Light_Base"/>

<!-- DARK Theme -->
<style name="Theme_Dark_Base" parent="@style/ContactPicker_Theme_Dark">
    <!-- ActionBarCompat -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_dark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark_dark</item>

    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/background_dark</item>
    <!--<item name="icTheme">@drawable/ic_palette_white_36dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="icPickContact">@drawable/ic_person_add_white_36dp</item>-->
</style>
```

and after apply directly on the ActivityPicker in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.onegravity.contactpicker.core.ContactPickerActivity"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:theme="@style/Theme_Light_picker">

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: The real issue was that the check happened before the theme was set in code. While your solution works, it doesn't fix the issue that you couldn't set the theme in code which is what you want if the app supports multiple themes (like dark and light theme). I fixed that with version 1.3.2.